# Sharepoint Foundation versus Server - Workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I have been doing research on Sharepoint 2010 Foundation vs Server in relation to Workflow. Here is what I've researched/setup:

- Installed Sharepoint 2010 Foundation with Visual Studio 2010 (SQL Server 2008 Express, Windows Server 2008 R2 already installed)
- Installed Sharepoint Designer and Visio 2010

I have been reading through Phil Wicklund's Sharepoint 2010 Workflows in Action.

Our decision point is whether to simply go with Sharepoint 2010 Server or Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.  I understand that Sharepoint 2010 Foundation does not allow Infopath forms.  I also understand it is missing some built in workflows (only offers three-state).

My question is, is there anything else I'm missing that Server has that Foundation doesn't have that would be considered a "show-stopper"? We are considering using Foundations as a platform for hosting various workflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using Sharepoint Foundation and if you have Visual Studio or even Sharepoint Designer (its free) then you can do lots of stuff even just around the Sharepoint Foundation.  Yes by default you can only have the built in "three-state" but no one is stopping you develop your own workflow and even your own forms but not as infopath but a proper form developed in .Net.  If you want to have and idea on whats the extent of customizing your Sharepoint check out this one http://anyrest.wordpress.com/tag/sharepoint/, all of the posts there are done in Sharepoint Foundation.

You can always start with foundation and if it does not suit your needs then you can always upgrade.